# How to convert dictionary with object to list of that type?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I convert the following dictionary to a List of Channel objects? I tried the ToList() method, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
List<Items> items = new List<Items>();

Dictionary<int, Items> foundItems = 
    statsCont.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.NumberOfItems)
        .Take(10)
        as Dictionary<int, Items>;
```

Comment: You you mean a List of Items objects?

Comment: Whats's relation between the `channels` and the `statsCont` variables? What's `statsCont` anyway?

Comment: Agree with @DarinDimitrov, can you please provide more detail as to what the relation is with those two?  Is `statsCont` already of type dictionary?

Comment: Sorry about that, I had some code in there. That statCont is a dictionary of <int,Items>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
List<Items> items = statsCont.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.NumberOfItems)
    .Take(10)
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried:

```
foundItems.Values.ToList();
```